# Does the non homogeneous ODE has ONE solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to be sure from the following ( if it is correct or not)  :

The second order linear non homogeneous ODE
$$y''+a(x)y'+b(x)y=f(x)$$
has a ONE solution called the particular solution yp .

But the general solution is 
$$y(x)=c_1y_1+c_2y_2+y_p$$ 
where 
$$c_1y_1+c_2y_2$$
is the solution of the corresponding homogeneous DE .

And the general solution is linearly dependent on the particular solution yp.
This is why we consider that we have ONE solution to a non-homogeneous ODE.

Comment: The inhomogeneous does not have ONE solution. It has infinitely many ones.

Comment: I mean that all of them depend on  the particular solution , so we have ONE independent solution ?

Comment: Any solution can be called "the particular solution", although we often choose a particular solution of a certain form if it is available.  The general solution is **not** "linearly dependent on the particular solution": it is a linear combination of the particular solution and $y_1$ and $y_2$.